# cx_oracle ThreadPoolExecutor with SessionPool and distributing loads for each Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, cx-oracle, threadpoolexecutor

I have an use case which consists of loading huge tables from Oracle to Snowflake.
The Oracle server sits far away from Snowflake endpoint, so we do have connection issues when loading tables (views in fact) bigger than 12 GB by spool script or cx_oracle.

I was thinking of using ThreadPoolExecutor with 4 threads max., to test, and use SessionPool. With this, I get a connection per thread, that's the whole point. So, this means I would have to distribute the data fetch by batches for each thread.
My question is: how can I achieve this? Is it correct to do something like:
"Select * from table where rownum between x and y" (not this syntax, I know...but you get my point), should I rely on OFFSET, ...?

My idea was that each thread gets a "slice" of select , fetches data by batches and writerows to csv in batches as well, because I'll rather have small files then a huge file, to send to snowflake.

```
def query(start_off, pool):
    start_conn = datetime.now()
    con = pool.acquire()
    end_conn = datetime.now()
    print(f"Conn/Acquire time: {end_conn-start_conn}")

    with con.cursor() as cur:
        start_exec_ts = datetime.now()
        cur.execute(QUERY, start_pos=start_off, end_pos=start_off+(OFFSET-1))
        end_exec_ts = datetime.now()
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        end_fetch_ts = datetime.now()
        total_exec_ts = end_exec_ts-start_exec_ts
        total_fetch_ts = end_fetch_ts-end_exec_ts
        print(f"Exec time : {total_exec_ts}")
        print(f"Fetch time : {total_fetch_ts}")
        print(f"Task executed {threading.current_thread().getName()}, {threading.get_ident()}")
    return rows


def main():
    pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(c.oracle_conn['oracle']['username'],
                                 c.oracle_conn['oracle']['password'],
                                 c.oracle_conn['oracle']['dsn'],
                                 min=2, max=4, increment=1,
                                 threaded=True,
                                 getmode=cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT
                                 )

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(query, d, pool) for d in range(1,13,OFFSET)]

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            # process your records from each thread
            print(repr(future.result()))
            # process_records(future.result())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, using fetchMany in query funcion , how could I send back the results so I can process them each time?

Comment: I believe the concept is that for each thread to maintain no data loss, each processed thread needs to be infallible. Using parameterized queries or offset should not be a big diffrence imo. However in case of failure of a thread you must be able to recover and reprocess the query regardless. I might consider using a queue for the parameterized queries/offset value such that if a thread fails the task is reassigned through the queue.

Comment: @neverMind This might not be what you are looking for, but have you considered using any of the data pipeline tools/platforms such as Hevo, Amazon S3, Striim, TEKsystems AMP which does not require any code and would prevent any data loss during moving/loading the data from Oracle to Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transfer the data by the python script

you can create a producer -> queue -> consumer workflow to do this

and the consumer rely on the ID of the data

**producer**

the producer fetch the IDs of the data

put "a slice of IDs" to the queue as a job

**consumer**

the consumers fetch the job from the queue

fetch the data with the IDs (e.g. "select * from table where id in ...")

save the data to somewhere

**example**

a quick example for such concept

```
import time
import threading
import queue
from dataclasses import dataclass

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

@dataclass
class Job:
    ids: list

jobs = queue.Queue()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
fake_data = [i for i in range(0, 200)]

def consumer():
    try:
        job = jobs.get_nowait()
        # select * from table where id in job.ids
        # save the data
        time.sleep(5)
        print(f"done {job}")
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)

def fake_select(limit, offset):
    if offset >= len(fake_data):
        return None
    return fake_data[offset:(offset+limit)]

def producer():
    limit = 10
    offset = 0
    stop_fetch = False
    while not stop_fetch:
        # select id from table limit l offset o
        ids = fake_select(limit, offset)
        if ids is None:
            stop_fetch = True
        else:
            job = Job(ids=ids)
            jobs.put(job)
            print(f"put {job}")
            offset += limit
            executor.submit(consumer)
        time.sleep(0.2)


def main():
    th = threading.Thread(target=producer)
    th.start()
    th.join()

    while not jobs.empty():
        time.sleep(1)

    executor.shutdown(wait=True)
    print("all jobs done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

besides,

if you want to do more operation after consumer fetching the data

you can do this in the consumer flow

or add another queue and consumer to do extra operations

the workflow will become like this

producer -> queue -> fetch and save data consumers -> queue -> consumer to do some extra operation